# Laravel test connection to SOAP WDSL and exception handling

Tags: php, exception, soap, laravel

I use the laravel framework and I want to check if a connection to Soap server was successful or not, without the app dying with fatal error.

Both this:

```
$this->client = @new SoapClient("http://some.url/test.wsdl");
                $this->session = $this->client->login("username", "password");
                if (is_soap_fault($this->session)) {
                   return "Error";
                }
```

And this:

```
try {
 $this->client = @new SoapClient("http://some.url/test.wsdl");
 $this->session = $this->client->login("username", "password");
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    return "Error";
}
```

Result in a fatal error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException

SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://some.url/test.wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://some.url/test.wsdl"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with this issue today as well. The problem is the Laravel error handler is interpreting this catchable error as a fatal error, and aborting the program as a result.

To counter this, you need to intercept the error prior to Laravel's internal error handler. This method varies depending on your Laravel version:

**Laravel 4.***

1. Go to your `globals.php` file. This should be in your `app\start\` folder.
2. Add the following code ([Thanks dmgfjaved](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6618)):

   ```
   App::fatal(function($exception)
   {   //If SOAP Error is found, we don't want to FATALLY crash but catch it instead
      if(strpos($exception->getMessage(), 'SOAP-ERROR') !== FALSE)
      {
        return '';
      }
   });
   ```

**Laravel 5.***

1. There is no `globals.php` file. All IoC calls are handled via `ServiceProviders`. Go to `app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php`.
2. Find the `render()` function.
3. Add the following code before the `return parent::render($request, $e);`

   ```
   if(strpos($e->getMessage(), 'SOAP-ERROR') !== false)
   {
       return false;
   }
   ```

This will remove the SoapFault error type from your error handler. Remember to catch the SoapFault as Laravel won't!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
try {
 $this->client = @new SoapClient("http://some.url/test.wsdl");
 $this->session = $this->client->login("username", "password");
} catch (\Throwable $e) {
    return "Error";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to actually ask the Soap client to throw a SoapFault instead of reporting an E_ERROR.

When the Soap client reports an E_ERROR, there is nothing for you to catch.

To fix this initialise you SoapClient like this:

```
$clientOptions = array(
    'exceptions' => true,
);

try {
    $client = new \SoapClient("foo.wsdl", $clientOptions);
} catch (\SoapFault $e) {
    // Do what you need to do!;
}

try {
    $result = $client->__soapCall($method, $data);
} catch (\SoapFault $e) {
    // Do what you need to do!;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I got soap to work in Laravel 5.1

1. clean install laravel 5.1
2. install [artisaninweb/laravel-soap](https://github.com/artisaninweb/laravel-soap)
3. create a controller SoapController.php

   ```
   <?php
   namespace App\Http\Controllers;
   use Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\Facades\SoapWrapper;
   class SoapController extends Controller {

   public function demo()
   {
       // Add a new service to the wrapper
       SoapWrapper::add(function ($service) {
           $service
               ->name('currency')
               ->wsdl('http://currencyconverter.kowabunga.net/converter.asmx?WSDL')
               ->trace(true);
       });

       $data = [
           'CurrencyFrom' => 'USD',
           'CurrencyTo'   => 'EUR',
           'RateDate'     => '2014-06-05',
           'Amount'       => '1000'
       ];

       // Using the added service
       SoapWrapper::service('currency', function ($service) use ($data) {
           var_dump($service->getFunctions());
           var_dump($service->call('GetConversionAmount', [$data])->GetConversionAmountResult);
       });
   }

   }
   ```
4. Create a route in your routes.php

   `Route::get('/demo', ['as' => 'demo', 'uses' => 'SoapController@demo']);`

Answer (score 0):

@Adam Link provided a good hint, but in Laravel 5.1, it appear stha tthere is not longer a render method in AppServiceProvider.

Instead, it has been moved to app\Exceptions\Handler.php