# display error of magento api soapclient

Tags: php, api, magento, laravel, soap

im working with laravel 4 framework and magento api soap. this is my login method:

```
    public function APIauthentication( $apiUser, $apiKey ) {

        $error = array();

        if( empty( $apiUser ) ) {
                $error[] = 'Unknown api user';
        }

        if( empty( $apiKey ) ) {
                $error[] = 'Invalid api key';
        }

        if( empty( $error ) ) {

                $client = $this->_getClient();
                $token = $client->login( $apiUser, $apiKey );
                $this->_setToken( $token );

                return $this->_apiJsonResult( $token );
        } else {
                return $this->_apiJsonResult( $error );
        }

}
```

now im getting on laravel screen SoapFault Access denied.

i need  to return error string if url is incorrect or API user/key is incorrect.

like this:

```
return Redirect::to('user/stores/magento/')->with('status', 'apie user or key is incorrect');
```

how to do this? there is fault code but i dont know how to log that
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html#Introduction-GlobalAPIFaults

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SoapFault is an Exception that needs to be caught.  The fault code and error string can be accessed via the Exception. Also, make sure the SoapClient is instantiated with the 'exceptions' option set to true, otherwise I believe PHP just throws a fatal error.

```
if( empty( $error ) ) {
    $client = $this->_getClient();
    try {
        $token = $client->login( $apiUser, $apiKey );
    } catch (SoapFault $e) {
        // login failed logic
        $faultcode = $e->faultcode; // ex: 2
        $message = $e->faultstring; // ex: Access denied.
        // return redirect, etc...
    }
    // login successful logic
    $this->_setToken( $token );

    return $this->_apiJsonResult( $token );
} else {
    return $this->_apiJsonResult( $error );
}
```

Comment: its work, but than im testing on the php file. when im testing in laravel error showing like this http://prntscr.com/6nlnzc

Comment: @HaroldasKerušauskas Is that file namespaced?  Try changing `catch (SoapFault $e)` to `catch (\SoapFault $e)`.

Comment: thank you its works :) maybe can you help how to return error if url incorect. there is my method:
`public function __construct( $wsdl ) {

  $client = new parent( $wsdl );
  $this->_setClient( $client );

 }`

Comment: error is Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://localhost:8888/magentof/api/soap/?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://localhost:8888/magentof/api/soap/?wsdl" in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/soap.php:31 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/soap.php(31): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://localhos...') #1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/soap.php(253): Client->__construct('http://localhos...') #2 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/soap.php on line 31

Comment: @HaroldasKerušauskas Since this exception is being thrown from the constructor, you need to handle it wherever you are instantiating this object.

Comment: there is my code: http://paste.ofcode.org/n8mwwR4GhRGtnryhtVm5Gr
if im writting incorect user name or key, its all good, but if incorect url im getting this:
http://prntscr.com/6nlze6

thanks for help

Comment: ant there is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25935303/laravel-test-connection-to-soap-wdsl-and-exception-handling

Comment: @HaroldasKerušauskas You would be better off asking another question. It looks like that issue is outside of the scope of this current question.